# How to perform a modal transition like the center button in the Instagram app with SwiftUI TabView?

Tags: swiftui

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showModal = false

    var body: some View {
        TabView {


            Text("Home View")
            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "house")
                    Text("Home")
                }
            }


            Text("Dummy View")
            .onAppear {
                self.showModal = true
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$showModal) {
                Text("Camera View")
            }
            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "camera")
                    Text("Camera")
                }
            }


            Text("Setting View")
            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                    Text("Setting")
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

When I tap the center camera button with above code,

1. "Dummy View" has been shown.
2. onAppear is called and self.showModal is set to true.
3. But, modal transition is not performed, and can not show the "Camera View".

How to perform a modal transition when tapped tab button with SwiftUI TabView?

---

Thank you krjw!

Finally, I have solved the problem with the following code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showModal = false

    var body: some View {
        TabView {


            Text("Home View")
            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "house")
                    Text("Home")
                }
            }


            Text("Dummy View")
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.showModal = true
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$showModal) {
                Text("Camera View")
            }
            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "camera")
                    Text("Camera")
                }
            }


            Text("Setting View")
            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                    Text("Setting")
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had trouble with that and I am not sure why, but `.sheet` always worked best for me when I put it on the very top of my view hierarchy. Additionally I wrapped the call in `.onAppear` to run explicitly on the main queue (UI) which got it working:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showModal = false

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Text("Home View")
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "house")
                        Text("Home")
                    }
            }

            Text("Dummy View")
                .onAppear {
                    print("Hallo")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.showModal = true
                    }
                }
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "camera")
                        Text("Camera")
                    }
            }

            Text("Setting View")
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "person")
                        Text("Setting")
                    }
            }

        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$showModal) {
            Text("Camera View")
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the great advice!
The problem has been solved.
It works fine just by executing `self.showModal = true` turn to the main queue using `DispatchQueue.main.async`.
It worked better for me when I placed the `.sheet` in the `Dummy View` , not the top view.
When I put the `.sheet` in the top view, I don't know why, but after returning from `Camera View` in the modal display, pressing the Home button or Setting button, `onAppear` of `Dummy View` was called and modal transition occurred again.